# Expo react native app crashes ONLY with internal testing becaue of missing androidClientId

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, google-signin, google-play-internal-testing

With development build, I have no problems but with a production build using internal testing, my app immidiately crashed because of following error:

```
Error: Client Id property `androidClientId` must be defined to use Google auth on this platform.
```

I added an androidClientId and there shouldnt be any issues because I have no problems logging in or using google auth, its only in internal testing. I dont understand why. Do I need to set up anything differently for internal testing?